# Check if a given path exists in a graph

Tags: java, graph

I'm using BFS to see if a given path exists in a graph:

```
static class Node{
    int data;
    Node next;

    public Node(int data){
        this.data = data;
    }
}

//Adjency List to store the reference to head of each Node/Vertice
static class AdjList implements Iterable<Integer>{
    Node head;
    public void add(int to){
        if(head==null){
            head = new Node(to);
        }else{
            Node temp = head;
            while(temp.next!=null)
                temp = temp.next;
            temp.next = new Node(to);
        }
    }


    //Used to iterate over the adjacency list while BFS
    @Override
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator(){
        Iterator<Integer> it = new Iterator<Integer>(){
            Node temp = head;
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext(){
                return temp!=null;
            }

            @Override
            public Integer next(){
                Node toRet = temp;
                temp = temp.next;
                return toRet.data;
            }

            @Override
            public void remove(){
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        };
        return it;
    }

}


static class Graph{
    AdjList[] lists;
    int numberOfNodes;

    public Graph(int numberOfNodes){
        lists = new AdjList[numberOfNodes];
        this.numberOfNodes = numberOfNodes;
        for(int i=0; i<numberOfNodes; i++){
            lists[i] = new AdjList();
        }
    }

    //Adds edge from/to vertice
    public void addEdge(int from, int to){
        lists[from].add(to);
    }


    public boolean BFS(int from, int to){
        LinkedList<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        queue.add(from);
        boolean[] visited = new boolean[numberOfNodes];
        visited[from]= true;

        while(!queue.isEmpty()){
            if(visited[to]==true)
                return true;
            int curr = queue.poll();
            System.out.print(curr + " ");
            Iterator<Integer> iter = lists[curr].iterator();
            while(iter.hasNext()){
                int currVal = iter.next();
                if(visited[currVal]==false){
                    queue.add(currVal);
                    visited[currVal]=true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;   
    }

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Graph myGraph = new Graph(3);
    myGraph.addEdge(0, 1);
    myGraph.addEdge(1,2);
    myGraph.addEdge(2,1);
    System.out.println("Path from 2 to 0 exists : " + Boolean.valueOf(myGraph.BFS(2,0)));
}
```

I could've used DFS for the same purpose which requires lesser memory than BFS, but since my `Graph` was pretty small, it wouldn't have made much of a difference. Apart from that, under what circumstances should I prefer either of them?

Comment: DFS may be more memory-efficient, that's true. However, if your graph is large, there is risk that DFS will recur too deep and cause stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the code, I'd have only 2 suggestions:

- Use brackets even for single-line `if`s. It improves readability and makes the code less error prone.
- Try not to shorten member names too much (like `iter` or `it` for example). It improves readability.

As for the chosen algorithm and possible alternative I'd suggest [Iterative Deepening DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search). It has the best of both [Depth-First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) and [Breadth-First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) - it's complete, finds the optimal solution, and doesn't use too much space.

Let me know if anything's unclear.